# UITableview cell issue with xcode6

Tags: uitableview, ios8, xcode6, uistoryboard

i m using xcode 6. iam working on a universal application. in my project one of my view contain a tableview cell (prototype) which give me a little problem. the problem is that since it is a universal application so cell made on the storyboard will be use by both iphone/ipad. i made a cell with autolayout and everything is fine, but now im facing problem regarding the size of cell and font size. since my application contain different size of font and cell size for iphone and ipad. can i use height for row function to solve cell height problem or is there any other work around for this and same thing goes for font size which are different for iphone and ipad. please let me know any other work around without using code for all this.  thanks.

Comment: what Problem you face

Comment: when we have two different storyboard, i can chose font size and cell size different for each ipad and iphone but since its universal now. how can i manage all this? im using sizing class with any any option.

Comment: vijay got my point ?

Answer (score 0):

Using category for label i fixed it by checking iphone or ipad device and giving it different font size. Thanks to apple new Xcode they added this feature in storyboard.